# My suggested edit was rejected while the same edit by another user was accepted. Why?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I had made a edit suggestion, which was the same as [this post revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14320396/2). I had made the same edit before this user's edit.

Then why was mine not accepted while the same edit by this user was accepted?

Comment: Why? Because the community is not perfect. We are only humans, and what one person thinks is acceptable, another rejects. The edit itself is borderline.

Comment: @Oded So hypothetically, if i have editing privileges, then i can first reject an edit and then make the same one myself ? (Just asking)

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: Btw, to clarify, the user finally making the edit played no part in the rejection of yours. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1330136 He might have wanted to approve but found it already rejected when he did so. Though that is mere speculation.

Comment: @Bart ok. No complaints. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're not completely identical. Compare [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1330136) with the [actual revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14320396/2) made by that user.

Anyway, that aside... notice the reason unanimously given by the users who rejected your edit (besides the users who approved it) — it was **too minor**:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

The thing about suggested edits from less privileged users is that we want to be sure you know how to contribute substantial edits, before we can trust you to make... smaller edits. This is why the edit review system exists and why such a rejection reason exists.

Some possible reasons why your edit was rejected as too minor could be:

- "Not needed" isn't a very good description of your edit
- You only corrected a typo and removed thanks

Admittedly, there isn't much more to address in the post (although that doesn't mean there isn't *anything* left), which could be why the other user submitted such a minor edit as well. But that's just my guess.

Your best course of action, going forward, is to look for other posts that have more room for improvement than just a wayward spelling error, a sign-off, and so on that you can put more effort into. Such posts are not few and far between, so you have plenty of opportunities to contribute meaningful edits to the site.

Comment: You don't need to read past the first word to see two major problems with the post that should have been corrected.  First, `Can't` uses an apostrophe, not a semi-colon.  (J0k fixed that one).  Next, the first and second sentences contain no subject.  They should start with `I`.  Given the fact that these very obvious mistakes were not included in the edit; it's very easy for the reviewers to call them "too minor".

Comment: *The thing about suggested edits from less privileged users is that we want to be sure you know how to contribute substantial edits, before we can trust you to make... smaller edits.* In a nutshell. +1