# Edit will be displayed after peer review

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, privileges, edits

I made an edit to a question on Stack Overflow and it said my edit would be displayed after peer review. A few moments later it said the question was edit by so-and-so. I clicked to see and they had made the same exact edits as me (except modifying one thing) and copy and pasted my whole paragraph explanation for the edits word for word... I'm wondering if this is just how the process appears or if they are trying to get reputation some how by stealing other's edits?

Here is the question: [How to detect only/specifically human voice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394274/how-to-detect-only-specifically-human-voice)

Comment: From your profile page you can access your activity including [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/773897/albert-renshaw?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). When you click on [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1352454) you are interested in, you can find out what happened with your edit - which users voted to approve, to reject, etc.

Comment: Between, Your both accounts ([SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/773897/albert-renshaw) and [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/208213/albert-renshaw)) are not associated.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163707/my-suggested-edit-was-rejected-while-the-same-edit-by-another-user-was-accepted/163709#163709

Comment: I know, I don't know show to make the accounts associated... I have the same eMail and user name yet they aren't linked /:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, The user already has 6k reputation, so they don't gain any more reputation from edits (you can only gain reputation from *suggested edits*, once you can just post them, the rep gain goes away).

More importantly, this is the result of pushing "improve" in the review queue. This *usually* means that your edit was good, but missing something.

Remember that an edit to a question or answer should fix *all* the problems, if possible. So if you find that there's a typo in the title, you should scan for useless greetings and problems in the tags as well.

Answer (score 8):

[Your suggested edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1352454). While reviewing your suggested edit that user clicked on <kbd>Improve</kbd> button. And removed some unnecessary words. Then he unchecked *Suggested edit was helpful* because your suggested edit was too minor. So community rejected your suggested edit.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is trying to steal your edits, but until you have enough reputation your edits need to be approved by reviewers. Those users with enough reputation may edit your post directly. It is a part of his/her job as a reviewer. Notice, if you make edits your reputation slowly grow by +2 rep for each approved edit.

Comment: You only get +2 rep if the suggested edit is approved, and nothing if it is rejected. See [How do suggested edits work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: No, it said no penalty is given if the suggested edit is rejected, but the reputation still awarded for the editing.

Comment: Quote for linked post: "When a suggested edit **is approved**, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation.". If it is rejected, you do not get a penalty, but neither will you get any rep. Giving rep for rejected edits will make it easy for others the abuse the system.

Comment: i don't know where did you get that "but neither will you get any rep", there's nothing appropriate in the post you mentioned