# Add a 2nd Edit Summary box in the queue to incentivize reviewers helping editors to improve their suggestions

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing and improving a suggested-edit I usually like to add in the Edit Summary box what I've additionally changed in the post, so the user who initially suggested the edit can visualize what he missed (at least what was missed under the reviewer's point of view). I usually write my name initials ("AS") after what was written by the editor, and then, add more info about the additional changes.

For example:

> improved formatting; AS - fixed typos, removed "thanks", added tag x

I started doing this because of two reasons:

1. The editor can learn and improve their future edits (make them more complete).
2. He/she can understand better why their avatar did not appear after the edit was submitted (it helps to reduce disagreement and consequently, [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164126/edit-will-be-displayed-after-peer-review) kind of threads on meta).

Now, the idea here is to add a second Edit Summary box for reviewers of suggested-edits. If the reviewer decides to improve the suggestion and also to fill in an explanation of the improvements, then the two messages (editor and reviewer) would be joint in just one in a way that would be clear to the editor what was added in the review.

For example:

user 1 writes in the current Edit Summary box:

> upper case in proper noun

The edit goes to the queue and there, a reviewer (user 2) decides to improve the post

In the (new) Edit Summary box 2 (which would appear beneath the Edit Summary box 1) he writes:

> code format

After the edit is submitted by user 2, the history on that specific edition stays:

user 1: upper case in proper noun; user 2: code format.

<sub>If after that, a new edit is submitted it would not accumulate with the messages from previous edits. It would start a new history message, like the current format.</sub>.

I believe this could yield a beneficial snowball effect because users would learn day by day with peers. Some users come back to see if their edit was approved or rejected and investigate what they could have done better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already possible.

When you click **Improve**, the "Edit Summary" will show what the suggesting editor added.

You as the Secondary, or Improving Editor, will then edit that edit summary to summarise what you tweaked or adjusted on the suggested edit.

After saving the edit you see the original from the user under 2000 reputation, and then you see the one that was added on top.

In most cases you don't see it because the user improving the edit leaves the edit summary as-is.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked this feature. So, it is not necessary to add my initials as I was doing before, but just to write the explanations. Having had reviewed a lot lately I believe most suggesting editors users do fill in the edit summary box. I guess the improving reviewers don't, and sometimes this causes the confusion. It would be nice if there were more graphical user interface features to incentivize reviewers to explain what they have added.