# Why did my edit get rejected but still show up as attributed to another user?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-user, rejected-edits

I suggested an edit to this question: [Should an internal DialogFragment class be static or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414908/should-an-internal-dialogfragment-class-be-static-or-not)

According to the edit review, my edit was [rejected by Community](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1719043) but the question only shows one edit which is the edit I made.  Only, instead of being owned by me, the edit is owned by the asker.

How is it that my edit got rejected, applied to the question, then credited to asker instead of me?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I understand how Community is attributed for edits and rejections.  I wanted to know why the edit was attributed to the asker.  I did however read that linked question to figure out why Community rejected the edit in the first place though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The edit was rejected automatically because it conflicted with an [edit the owner of the post made](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15414908/revisions).

I suspect the OP *updated* his edit after he saw your suggestion was rejected by a smaller change he made. The smaller edit automatically rejected your edit, then the OP incorporated your change after seeing the notification of the suggested edit; if done within the first 5 minutes of the small edit no new entry is made in the revision history.

Comment: So the asker made an edit to his own question and because of that, my entire edit is attributed to him regardless of which edit was more detailed?  This is my first run in with improperly attributed edits so I'm just curious.

Comment: He just happened to have made the same changes.

Comment: Don't worry, you get used to it.

Comment: @MCeley See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163707/my-suggested-edit-was-rejected-while-the-same-edit-by-another-user-was-accepted

Comment: That's interesting that he would've made the same edits or at least similar edits considering the original wording of the question.  I'll have to keep an eye on this in the future in order to sate my own curiosity about how often this happens since, as I said, this is my first run in with this.  Thanks.

Comment: @MCeley It's less common to see this behavior by the OP, it's not so rare to see this behavior by a high rep user/mod editing the post (and then going back to incorporate your edit if they realized you posted a conflicting one).

Comment: @Servy That I have seen before but usually with a comment on the edit saying they were improving the edit.  In this case the OP kept my comment without adding anything which is what really threw me.